# Does Gremlin bothE() double count Edges?

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to count number of objects in my graph. However, the Vertices must belong to a specific set of keys, so I do the following:

For Vertices, I use:
`g.V().has('document_id', P.within(list_o_keys)).count().next()`

For Edges, I use:
`g.V().has('document_id', P.within(list_o_keys)).bothE().count().next()`

Since I have relationships between those Vertices, does this result in **double counting of Edges**?
e.g. for a relationship A->B it will count as 2 Edges since `bothE()` will return edges out of A and edges into B?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wouldn't call it a double counting of edges. It counts the incoming edges then it counts the outgoing edges:

```
gremlin> g.addV('a').as('a').
......1>   addV('b').as('b').
......2>   addE('link').from('a').to('b').
......3>   addE('link').from('b').to('a').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').bothE().count()
==>2
```

Note that it's not counting the edges out of A and into B. It's counting edges out of A and into A. If you want one or the other then you would use `outE()` or `inE()` depending upon what you needed.

Comment: "It's counting edges out of A and into A." It was a bit misleading for me, for a minute I thought that you mean edges starting from the A vertex and ending in the A vertex. I did not understand what you mean, because there is no vertex specified that would have an edge pointing back to itself. I leave it here, maybe it will help another graph db rookie in the future

Answer (score 2):

It will count them twice in this case, as shown in the following example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(1,4).count()
==>2
gremlin> g.V(1,4).bothE().count()
==>6
gremlin> g.V(1,4).bothE().dedup().count()
==>5
```

`dedup()` is the easiest way to prevent that. Also, note that you can combine the two traversals:

```
gremlin> g.V(1,4).fold().
           project('a','b').
             by(count(local)).
             by(unfold().bothE().dedup().count())
==>[a:2,b:5]
```